# How to compress a directory to tar.xz with compression level and multithreading via CMake?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am trying to compress a directory as `.tar.xz` under Windows with CMake tools.

I want the following three things with priority in that order of importance:

1. The root directory of the `tar` should be different from my working directory.
2. Use maximum number of threads to speed up the compression.
3. Set the compression level.

I have found three ways to realize this:

- [CMake `file` `ARCHIVE_EXTRACT` statement](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#archive-create)

  1. ❌ Can not set working directory (➕ workaround possible by sub-script call via [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html))
  2. ❌ No multithreading support
  3. ✅ Can set compression level
- [CMake `tar` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-tar) via [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html)

  1. ✅ Can set working directory (by `execute_process`)
  2. ❌ No multithreading support
  3. ❌ Can not set compression level
- [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/archive.html) via [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html)

  1. ✅ Hopefully can set working directory (by `execute_process`?)
  2. ✅ Hopefully can enable multithreading support by [`CPACK_ARCHIVE_THREADS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/archive.html#variable:CPACK_ARCHIVE_THREADS) or [`CPACK_THREADS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_THREADS)?
  3. ❌ Nothing found.

The first point I can apparently implement with any of these approaches. Multithreading seems to be possible only with the CPack approach.

Unfortunately I did not manage to implement the approach via `cpack`.

Is there any way to fulfill all three points or at least the first two ones?